# Why do I have a memory leak in UIApplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I have an iphone app project.  I analysed it using instruments memory leak tool.  According to instruments I have 2 leaks the Trace is as follows:

`start main UIAplicationMain _run CFRunLoopInMode CFRunLoopRunSpecific PurpleEventCallback _UIAplicationHandleEvent sendEvent: handleEvent:withNewEvent:`

After this trace there are two separate traces.  What causes this and how can I fix it?

edit: 
The  leak is on the second line according to instruments

```
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); //leak
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `NSAutoReleasePool` for the threads?

That second method looks like some sort of callback being invoked by another component or system thread.

In the implementation, create a `NSAutoReleasePool` at the top and release it when the method is done:

```
void MyCallback {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  // do stuff
  [pool release];
}
```

Comment: When I first created the project(window based application template) I used the main.m that was created.  According to instruments their is a leak on the second line: 


NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;

Answer (score 0):

It might be a false positive.  UIApplicationMain probably creates a few objects that are intended to hang around for as long as the application exists and therefore never bothers to release them.